# Angular 7 router path with GET parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular2-routing

I've been searching for hours but can't find a working solution for my issue...

My angular application redirects the user to an oAuth2 API that returns a jwt via GET parameters. I found out how to read GET params with angular but my problem is a different thing:

```
{path: 'authenticate', component: AuthenticationComponent}
```

This is the route I set up for my AuthenticationComponent. It works as expected without any additional parameters but with a single get param ('/authenticate?jwt=123' instead of '/authenticate') it doesn't work any more and my '**' route is activated.

One workaround would be another site (not written in angular) that redirects the user to the angular page and transforms the GET param to a URL param ('/authenticate?jwt=123' => '/authenticate/123') and change my route path to 'authenticate/:jwt' but I want to do it with my angular application.

Please help me

Comment: Please produce a working link of your problem, It seems to work for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqv8jx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts. You can use StackBlitz to reproduce your issue easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a matcher in the routes like this
`{ component: AuthenticateComponent, matcher: authenticate}` and authenticate is a function like this

```
function authenticate(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    return url[0].path=="authenticate"?{consumed: url}: null;
}
```

this will match the route to AuthenticateComponent and in the component you can get the jwt like this `this.route.snapshot.queryParams['jwt']`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

set router like this

```
{path: 'authenticate/:jwt', component: AuthenticationComponent}
```

and get the jwt value in component

```
// top component
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
// constructor arg
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
// user method or ngOnInit inside
this.route.params['value'].jwt
```

next import route module in your module

```
// top module
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// import object
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([])]
```

It's work

Answer (score 0):

If you've injected [**`Router`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) as a dependency, you'll need to [**`navigate`**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) like this:

```
this.router.navigate( ['authenticate'], { queryParams: { jwt: '123'}});
```

Or if you're using the [**`routerLink`**](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink), use it like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/authenticate']" [queryParams]="{ jwt: '123'}">Authenticate</a>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.